# Split Screen with certain applications: Does it only work on the primary display?

Tags: display, macos

I'm running El Capitan with two displays.

I am trying split screen and it works fine for all applications on the primary screen (when enabling that each screen has their own spaces), but for some applications it doesn't work on my secondary display.

For instance, when trying to add iTunes and Mail to the same split screen, the cursor turns into a white circle with an 'X' in the middle, and they won't join up in the same screen.

Is this expected behaviour?

Primary screen: External 27'' HP display.
Secondary screen: 15'' internal retina display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in both my displays.
What happens if you try to move a split screen from your primary display to your secondary display?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I retried this morning, and I can no longer reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok. I have managed to reproduce it. I will add the details to the question.

Comment: I have seen your edit and tried to reproduce it but it works fine in my system. Can you check what build of El Capitan you are using?
(About this Mac > System Report > Software)
And by the way, I have seen blogs writing about not being able to use split screen with iTunes, so there's a great possibility that this is a bug and the only way to fix it is to get as much people to send feedback to Apple.

Comment: I'm running 15A284

Comment: Me, too. >_<
But the fact that there had been at list one time when you actually got it to work makes me think that it is indeed some sort of glitch...

Comment: The fact that it's working for you also points to the fact that it's not expected behaviour.